# Cannot get React to act on button click except via addEventListener

Tags: javascript, reactjs, preact

I would like to know what I did wrong in trying to get the onclick handler executed using reactjs, for a button when specifying it inline. The only way I got it to work was using `addEventListener`.

It's my understanding that this should work: `<button onClick={this.togglePop}>Modify</button>`

where `togglePop` is a function in the class rendering the document (as in the code below). However it produces the error `Uncaught TypeError: this.l[l.type] is not a function at HTMLButtonElement.P (preact.min.js:1)`

The way I did get it to work was using
`document.getElementById("modify10").addEventListener('click', this.togglePop);`

I am using the Chrome browser. This is my first time using React, and I've not done a lot of javascript. Amongst many, one of the best sites I found was https://www.debuggr.io/react-setstate-is-not-a-function/ but I still couldn't solve the inline problem. Out of frustration, I tried a variety of ways, which remain below for your amusement, if nothing else. Please refer to the button declarations in the render method.

```
class DashSettings extends Component {
  state = {
  system_id: null, system_name: null,
  seen_systemid_popup: false
  };
  togglePop = () => {
    console.log("a");
    this.setState({
      seen_systemid_popup: !this.state.seen_systemid_popup
    });
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('/api/cfg/get')
        .then(r => this.setState(r.data))
        .catch(e => console.log(e));
    var self = this;
    var f = function(reader) {
      return reader.read().then(function(result) {
        var data = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, result.value);
        self.setState(JSON.parse(data));
        if (!result.done) return f(reader);
      });
    };

    // ********* This gets the modify10 button to work ************************
    document.getElementById("modify10").addEventListener('click', this.togglePop);
  }
  
  render(props, state) {
    return html`<div id="dashboard">
    <table id="settings_table">
      <tr><th></th><th><h5>Current Setting</h5></th></tr>
        <tr><td><div class="setting_label">System Id:   </div></td>
        <td><div class="setting_value">${state.system_id}</div></td>
        <td>
          <div>
          <!-- Unless stated otherwise, all buttons below generate this error: Uncaught TypeError: this.l[l.type] is not a function at HTMLButtonElement.P (preact.min.js:1)
          I even tried both onclick and onClick -->
          <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm" id="modify1" onClick={this.togglePop}>Modify1</button>
          <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm" id="modify2" onClick="{this.togglePop}">Modify2</button>
          <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm" id="modify3" onClick="{() => this.togglePop}">Modify3</button>
          <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm" id="modify4" onClick={this.togglePop()}>Modify4</button>
          <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm" id="modify5" onClick="{this.togglePop()}">Modify5</button>
          <!-- button class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm" onClick={() => this.togglePop}>Modify6</button> -->
          <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm" id="modify7" onClick={this.props.togglePop}>Modify7</button>
          <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm" id="modify8" onClick={props.togglePop}>Modify8</button>
          <!-- <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm" id="modify9" onClick={() => this.togglePop()}>Modify9</button>
          Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '' is not a valid attribute name. -->
          <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm" id="modify10">Modify10</button>
        ...
```

The code above is in app.js used in:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="preact.min.js"></script>
    <script src="preact-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="htm.min.js"></script>
    <script src="history.min.js"></script>
    <script src="linkstate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="axios.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it is using Hyperscript Tagged Markup (HTM) having the section in the `html wrapper) a '$' is required in front of the '{'. The inline definition should be:

`<button onClick=${this.togglePop}>Modify</button>`

For HTM, see github.com/developit/htm

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that you're not binding the event handler correctly as your render function is wrapped in "html ``"

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm" id="modify1" onClick={this.togglePop} // <-- seems to be string not an actual interpolation>Modify1</button>
```

Can you try to use render by just returning jsx (i.e., just remove the html wrapping)?

Comment: I noticed no html wrapper in examples I'd seen. But when I replace the html wrapping with brackets, as in a function call, I get an error ```Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' ``` at the <div>.

Comment: Refer to Hyperscript Tagged Markup for the html wrapper. See https://github.com/developit/htm